# java how to use a variable in method from another method

Tags: java, methods

I have tried something like that : but the error appears:

SEVERE: null
null
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'MYUSER' cannot be null

while it shouldn't? Also I would like to ask if there are some bad practices in my program.
any tips?

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */



public class Main extends JFrame  {


   String text;

  public Main() throws HeadlessException {

    //opis
    JLabel opis = new JLabel("Opis: ");
    JTextField opisTextField = new JTextField();
    opisTextField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
    add(opis);
    add(opisTextField);



//jak klikniemy w przycisk program doda wartosci wpisane do bazy danych.
    Button z = new Button("Dodaj do bazy danych"); 

     add(z);
    z.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

      @Override
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){}
      @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}
      @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
      @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}
      @Override
     public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {


        Main m = new Main();
        m.text = opisTextField.getText();






    });

  }

public void  readDataBase()  throws Exception {
    try {
      // this will load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      // setup the connection with the DB.
      connect = DriverManager
          .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/feedback?"
              + "user=sqluser&password=sqluserpw");

      // statements allow to issue SQL queries to the database
      statement = connect.createStatement();
      // resultSet gets the result of the SQL query


      // preparedStatements can use variables and are more efficient
      preparedStatement = connect
          .prepareStatement("insert into  FEEDBACK.COMMENTS values (default, ?, ?, ?, ? , ?, ?)");
        // "myuser, webpage, datum, summary, COMMENTS from FEEDBACK.COMMENTS");
        // parameters start with 1

     preparedStatement.setString(1, text);

      preparedStatement.executeUpdate();



      // remove again the insert comment


    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
      throw e;
    } finally {
     // close();
    }

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    new Main().setVisible(true);

  }

}
```

Comment: Please don't paste 100s of lines of code.  Instead, construct a small example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Someone is doing homework i guess :D

Comment: One of the bad practices is that your code is not indented properly.

Comment: Because you can't do that.

Comment: Your title has precisely zero to do with the exception.

Comment: Im trying to use  Main m = new Main();
        m.text = opisTextField.getText(); and then      preparedStatement.setString(1, text); but program says that text is null and I have no idea why.

Comment: @user3717707-Try m.text instead of text in preparedStatement.setString(1,m.text).

Comment: Main m = new Main();
     preparedStatement.setString(1, m.text); same error.

Comment: @EJP is right. Change your title according to the question, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry could not go through all the code but it looks like you declared `String text;` and you never provided it a value and you are passing this value to username `preparedStatement.setString(1, text);` which cannot be null as per error.

Comment: Thanks I fixed it by  replacing  Main m = new Main();
        m.text = opisTextField.getText(); with  text = opisTextField.getText(); weird because It didn't worked before like that.